# How order Percentage field in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering when I order by DESC the percentage value it give me not correct:

## Before Order

10%
70%
99%
90%
100%

## After Order

99%
90%
70%
100%
10%

Actually it's should be 100% is up. 
Any body can help me on that?

## My order Code:

```
public Cursor queue_FRUIT()
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_LEVEL, KEY_CORRECT, KEY_INCORRECT, KEY_DATE, KEY_PERCENTAGE, KEY_RESULT};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_FRUIT, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE+" DESC, " + KEY_PERCENTAGE+" DESC", "10");
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: But in this code you are ordering for KEY_DATE as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query result is because the column ordering is handled as String. The `KEY_PERCENTAGE` column shall be defined as `INTEGER` type instead of `TEXT`.

In this case you must store just the value without '%' character.